# Move an EC2 instance to a different VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-ami

I have an EC2 instance in VPC1.
It has a two block devices: `/dev/sda1` (root device) and `/dev/sdb`

I want to use boto3 to move this EC2 instance to VPC2. VPC1 and VPC2 are on us-east-1.

What are my options? I am guessing I need to select 1 from the following options.

1. Stop the instance in VPC1, create a snapshot and launch a new instance from this instance in VPC2.
2. Create an AMI from the instance in VPC1 and create a new instance in VP2 from this AMI.

Which approach makes more sense? Basically, I am trying to create a script that the owners of these EC2 instances can execute to "move" their Ec2 instances from VPC1 to VPC2.

Thanks and stay safe.

Comment: 1 and 2 are basically same thing. In order to create an AMI you must snapshot and in order to create a new instance from a snapshot you need to convert it to an AMI

Comment: Since you have multiple volumes, it would be easier to create an AMI (make sure to include both volumes!). You should also consider other things that need to be "moved", such as security groups and tags.

Answer (score 6):

You want to create an AMI from the running instance in VPC1, then go to VPC2 and launch that AMI to migrate the instance.